# How to get a closed-form for this sum?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I'm trying to calculate the $[x^n]F(x)$ from a generating function $F(x) = \frac{1}{(1-2x^2)^2}$ and I came across with this expression involving a sum:

$$2^n\sum_{k=0}^n k^k (n-k)^{n-k}$$

What I did so far was calculate the $[x^n]\frac{1}{1-2x^2}$, witch is $(2n)^n$ if I'm not wrong, and then making a convolution $\frac{1}{1-2x^2} . \frac{1}{1-2x^2}$ to find $[x^n]$.

My question is, how can I obtain a closed-form for the sum above?

Comment: Assuming that you meant $n$ instead of $N$ in the upper limit, that sum is a convolution of $a(k) = k^k$ with itself. So if you knew the generating function for $a(n)$ (which might not be known) then you know how to find your sum.

Comment: I would suggest differentiation of $\frac1{(1-2x^2)}$ to obtain $\frac{4x}{(1-2x^2)}$ and to work from there. The convolution seems...convoluted.

Comment: Yes I meant $n$ @rwbogl Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried entering the sum into the OEIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that based on the series 
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$$
that
$$\frac{1}{1- 2 \, x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n} \, x^{2n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n/2} \, \left(\frac{1+(-1)^{n}}{2}\right) \, x^n.$$

From this then:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1- 2 x^2)^2} &= \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \sum_{s=0}^{\infty} 2^{(r+s)/2} \, \left(\frac{1+(-1)^{r}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1+(-1)^{s}}{2}\right) \, x^{r+s} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{s=0}^{n} 2^{n/2 -2} \, (1+(-1)^{n-s})(1+(-1)^{s}) \, x^{n} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n/2 - 2} \, (1 + (-1)^n) \, \sum_{s=0}^{n} (1 + (-1)^{s}) \, x^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  2^{n/2 -3} \, [2 (n+1) (1 + (-1)^n) + (1 + (-1)^n)^2] \, x^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2^{n/2} \, (n + 2) \, (1 + (-1)^{n})}{4} \right) \, x^n. 
\end{align}

Alternatively using
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) \, x^{n}$$
then
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1- 2 x^2)^2} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n} \, (n+1) \, x^{2n} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2^{n/2} \, (n+2) \, (1 + (-1)^{n})}{4} \right) \, x^n.
\end{align}

Comment: I can understand now.. Thank you so much